# How to filter from 100 milllion rows of data in Django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have a table that contains 100 million rows of data and has no relation to another table. A MySQL database is used. When I try to filter data from the table using the ORM, it takes 10 to 12 minutes to show the results. 
Is there any solution to minimize the time?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    Open = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    High = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Low = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Close = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Volume = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Dividends = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    StockSplits = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)


    query = MyModel.objects.filter(ticker=ticker)
```

Comment: Try running async code, you need to put the queries into separate functions, in a `@sync_to_async` decorator. You might also want to think of optimizing the queries (or your database!), maybe use raw sql when you're calling the db? 10 to 12 minutes, is a LOT of time.

Comment: @nigel239 how to optimize the query? If I use raw SQL, will it reduce the time?

Comment: Well, I can't tell you how to optimize it without models and queries. Using raw SQL will improve time, IF you specify only the fields you need. Or, if you have some large aggregations, you might want to look into optimizing those. You can always look at the raw SQL queries by specyfing `.query` after your query function. I.E. `MyModel.objects.all().query` @mr_fahad

Comment: @nigel239
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    Open = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    High = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Low = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Close = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Volume = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Dividends = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    StockSplits = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
MyModel.objects.filter(ticker=ticker)

this is the query

Comment: This query should take around 10-50ms tops if the database is local, are you fetching stuff from a website/api before querying? Or after querying? @mr_fahad

Comment: @nigel239 yes fetching from a website and then stored in a database and then querying. This project was hosted on a VPS server.

Comment: Ehhm, fetch the data asynchronously, do it nightly, do it with celery, but please, do not let the user wait for your website to finish api calls. This isn't because of the ORM, this is because of you fetching from a website.

Comment: @nigel239 I used apscheduler to do that.  the scheduler is collecting data and stores it in  database.

Comment: @nigel239 my other API is working fine.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.python-httpx.org/ it allows you to easily make asynchronous calls to API's. Calling the api's asynchronously, and creating the models when you've already fetched the data, is going to be the way. Financial data like stocks can take a lot of time to fetch. Can you pre-download it, maybe? Does the package you use provide an option for that?

Comment: I think async call along with pagination would be helpful

Comment: @nigel239 yes it will take time to scrap data and data are updated every few months. So the scheduler inserts data when data are coming from that website.

Comment: Is the `ticker` column indexed?

Comment: @mr_fahad would you mind timing the query? After that, we'll know what needs fixing.

Comment: @snakecharmerb no

Comment: @nigel239 this query takes 10-15 minutes to execute.

Comment: @mr_fahad, as Snakecharmerb mentioned, then start indexing. Also, paginate the data. You are retreiving wayyyy too many records at a time. Can you split up the task? How many tickers are you retreiving from? `MyModel.objects.filter(ticker=ticker).count()`

Comment: @nigel239 105000 tickers in my table. Does pagination reduce the time?

Comment: @nigel239 should i try MyModel.objects.filter(ticker=ticker).count() this query ?

Comment: Pagination would reduce time, as you're reducing the data into chunks.  Is there no other way you could reduce the amount of tickers retreived? Do you know how to optimize databases? @mr_fahad no need, you told me the count.

Comment: my research says that it depends on the hardware that handles rows. there is no way to reduce the ticker. @nigel239

Comment: @mr_fahad set up a cache backend for the queries. This'll cut down time by a lot. If the objects are cached anyways. If they are not cached, you will need to fetch from database, but the next time it'll be faster. Set a high timeout value for the cache. Look at options like database indexing, maybe sharding?

Comment: @nigel239 good idea to use cache backend. But is it work fine because the data is continuously updated? scheduler updated data if the data was not in the table.

Comment: Ehhm, yes and no? If the old data changes, no, this wont work well. Otherwise, if you just keep adding new data, you can just fetch it from the cache, append the created model to the queryset, and then just put it back into cache. The way you would append to the queryset is `my_queryset | mymodel.objects.filter(pk=created_model.pk)`

Comment: @nigel239 suppose you search for the Apple ticker. Once the data related to this ticker is in the cache, it will always show from cache. But new data related to this ticker is inserted every moment.

Comment: Yes, I'll explain. 1. Once a ticker is created, we get the queryset from the cache. 2. We then use that created model to `filter(pk=created_instance.pk)` 3. We then append the querysets together, using the `|` operator. 4. We put the objects back into the cache. This way the cache keeps getting updated.

Comment: @nigel239 Seems understandable

Answer (score -1):

One of the main drawbacks of ORM in large projects is that it is slow
But djago allows to execute sql command

you can use this:

```
response = MyModel.objects.raw('your_sql_command')
```

or

```
from django.db import connection

context=[]

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("your_sql_command")
while True :
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if res:
        context.append(res)
    else:
        break
cursor.close()
```

you can read more in :
[Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/)